# Combinatorial Geometry explanation

Tags: combinatorics, definition, intuition, combinatorial-geometry

I do not understand what is going on in $(4)$: for every flat $E \in \mathcal F$, $E \ne X$, the flats that cover $E$ in $\mathcal F$ partition the remaining parts.

> What is meant by "the flats that cover $E$ in $\mathcal F$ partition the remaining parts."?

---

---

[image]

Comment: Well, the sentence that starts with "This latter property..." seems to give some motivation for (and explanation of) property $(4)$. But I take it this doesn't entirely help?

Comment: No. I am not too familiar with geometry.

Comment: @pjs36 What is meant by "...partition the remaining parts"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain this via an analogy to (linear) geometry into two dimensions, call the space $L$.

You will have 4 "types" of flats: the empty set $\phi$, single points $\{\{p\}: p \in L\}$ and all lines $\{\{\ell\}: \ell \in L\}$, and $L$ itself. Single points cover the empty flat, a line that contains a point covers that point, and L covers each line.

Lets fix a point, call it $p$. Then any two lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ that cover $p$ (i.e., contain $p$ as a point) are disjoint when $p$ is excluded. Moreover, every point in $L-\{p\}$ will be contained in some line that covers $p$ (i.e., some line through $p$). Thus all the lines through $p$ (i.e., all the flats that cover $p$) partition the remaining points (i.e., the lines through $p$ contain all points in $L-\{p\}$ and no two lines intersect in $L-\{p\}$).

Try to relate this "inclusion" structure for families of subsets when working with discrete geometries.

Comment: How do we know every point in $L-\{p\}$ will be contained in some line that covers $p$?

Comment: This example is just linear geometry in two dimensions. Think of a sheet of paper. Draw a point on it, call it $p$ as in the explanation above. Take any other point on the sheet of paper, call it $q$. You can always find a line on the sheet of paper that goes through $p$ and $q$ (take a ruler and line up $p$ and $q$). The point $q$ is a point in $L-\{p\}$ in the explanation above.

This works for every point $q$ that is different from $p$. Also if you draw all the lines through $p$ you will cover the entire sheet of paper.